# Error when deploying Django/Mezzanine with Git (but not with SFTP)

Tags: django, git, sftp, mezzanine, cartridge

My web app is working fine on my ubuntu server and now it's time to deploy to a web hosting (dreamhost). I am using Django 1.9 and Mezzanine Cartridge cms and ecommerce framework.

I have copied to a subdomain of the web hosting the source code files and the static files, using SFTP, and the site worked fine.

But when I tried to use "git clone" to deploy the app source code to another subdomain, I had a strange problem: "thumbnails" pictures does not show at small size, but at full-size. The static files are the same previously mentioned. I just used a symbolic link for that.

This is a kind of "generic" question. What may I be missing when using Git instead of SFTP. What can possibly be wrong?

Below a sample of HTML generated by SFTP and Git copies of the app.

SFTP copy:

```
<ul id="product-images-large" class="list-unstyled list-inline">
<li id="image-5-large" >
    <a class="product-image-large" href="/static/media/uploads/fabrica/tijolo_1.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="/static/media/uploads/fabrica/.thumbnails/tijolo_1.jpg/tijolo_1-0x300.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive col-xs-12">
    </a>
</li>
```

Git copy:

```
<ul id="product-images-large" class="list-unstyled list-inline">
<li id="image-5-large" >
    <a class="product-image-large" href="/static/media/uploads/fabrica/tijolo_1.jpg">
        <img alt="" src="/static/media/uploads/fabrica/tijolo_1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive col-xs-12">
    </a>
</li>
```

There is a reference to a /.thumbnails/ folder on the first case, but not on the second.

Any help is welcome.
Thank you,

Marcio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mezzanine-users/I32IquBhL5g/smujMP2vBQAJ

This issue is not related to Git or Rsync.